# CSS3 animation not working outside Firefox

Tags: css, animation, cross-browser

I have some buttons on my website to save, edit or delete content. I want the buttons to 'pop' on hover-over, using a CSS3 Animation. It works fine in Firefox, but in all other tested browsers (IE, Opera, Chrome and Safari) it fails to do the animation. It only does the transition on the opacity.

I've searched Google for familiar problems but I can't find a solution. Does anyone of you have an idea how I can fix this?

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tqk5a74x/

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-buttons" rowspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="action-icon save" value="Save" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.save { background: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gloss-basic-icons-by-momentum/16/save.png') 50% 50% no-repeat; }

.save {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.action-icon {
    display:inline-block;
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity:.5;
    -webkit-transition:.2s;
    transition:.2s;
}

.action-icon:hover {
    -webit-animation: hover .2s;
    animation: hover .2s;
    -webkit-transition:.2s;
    transition:.2s;
    opacity:1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hover {
    0% {-webkit-background-size: 100%;}
    40% {-webkit-background-size: 50%;}
    75% {-webkit-background-size: 120%;}
    100% {-webkit-background-size: 100%;}
}

@keyframes hover {
    0% {background-size: 100%;}
    40% {background-size: 50%;}
    75% {background-size: 120%;}
    100% {background-size: 100%;}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake:

```
.action-icon:hover {
    -webit-animation: hover .2s; /* Missing 'k' in 'webkit'*/
    ....
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tqk5a74x/1/)

As for IE, I don't believe `background-size` is animatable. Opera, not a clue

How about a slight change to your animation which should work across the board:

```
@keyframes hover {
    0% {transform: scale(1)}
    40% {transform: scale(0.5)}
    75% {transform: scale(1.2)}
    100% {transform: scale(1)}
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tqk5a74x/2/)

```css
.save {
  background: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gloss-basic-icons-by-momentum/16/save.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
.save {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.action-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: .5;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}
.action-icon:hover {
  -webkit-animation: hover .2s;
  animation: hover .2s;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
  opacity: 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.5)
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(1.2)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.5)
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(1.2)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td-buttons" rowspan="2">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="action-icon save" value="Save" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was dumb. Thanks! It works fine in Chrome, now. However, it doesn't work in the other browsers. Should I use extra prefixes? Or should webkit suffise?